# Passing in as command parameter the value of a WPF ListView GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, listviewitem, gridviewcolumn

In an WPF `ListView` I have `ListViewItem`s that consist of three columns, first column is an auto-increment column, second one is a `TextBox` and the last one contains two buttons (Edit and Delete) in the same column.

My `ListView` now looks as below:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          AlternationCount="{Binding pathList.Count}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding pathList}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="#" x:Name="LvItemId"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Command sentence" Width="350" CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameColumnTemplate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Edit / Delete" CellTemplate="{StaticResource AddDelItemTemplate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Below the `CellTemplate`s:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FirstRowTemplate1">
    <Grid Width="190">
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddCommand, ElementName=MyListView}" 
                Width="180" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="NextRowTemplate1">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding PathString}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="NameColumnTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonPresenter"
                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NextRowTemplate1}"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Add}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonPresenter"  
                    Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource FirstRowTemplate1}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Add}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonPresenter"
                    Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource NextRowTemplate1}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="FirstRowTemplate2"/>
<DataTemplate x:Key="NextRowTemplate2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditCommand, ElementName=MyListView}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LvItemId, Path=WhatToPutHere}"/>
        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DelCommand, ElementName=MyListView}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LvItemId, Path=WhatToPutHere}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddDelItemTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonPresenter"
            Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"  
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NextRowTemplate2}"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Add}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonPresenter"
                    Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource FirstRowTemplate2}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Add}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonPresenter"
                    Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource NextRowTemplate2}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

When Edit or Delete button are clicked I want to pass in as a command parameter the value that first `GridViewColumn` has for that `ListViewItem`. How can I do this?

For example:

```
<Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditCommand, ElementName=MyListView}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LvItemId, Path=WhatToPutHere}"/>
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DelCommand, ElementName=MyListView}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LvItemId, Path=WhatToPutHere}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridViewColumn` defines the column itself, how it is populated, e.g. template, binding or width, but it does not have a reference to any of the items generated by the item container generator.

In case of the first column you can copy the binding for the attached property `AlternationIndex`:

```
<Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
```